# What is the least amount of privileges (Administrator, db_owner, etc ) for a user to perform Backup and Restore in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What is the least amount of privileges (Administrator, db_owner, etc) for a user to perform following in SQL Server ?

1. Backup
2. Restore

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Because the answer varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For backups the db_backupoperator fixed database role is the least amount of privileges needed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187510.aspx

For Restores, If the database being restored does not exist, the user must have CREATE DATABASE permissions to be able to execute RESTORE.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186858.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the documentation...

#### [Restore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx#Anchor_11)

> If the database being restored does not exist, the user must have
>   CREATE DATABASE permissions to be able to execute RESTORE. If the
>   database exists, RESTORE permissions default to members of the
>   sysadmin and dbcreator fixed server roles and the owner (dbo) of the
>   database (for the FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT option, the database always
>   exists).
>
> RESTORE permissions are given to roles in which membership information
>   is always readily available to the server. Because fixed database role
>   membership can be checked only when the database is accessible and
>   undamaged, which is not always the case when RESTORE is executed,
>   members of the db_owner fixed database role do not have RESTORE
>   permissions.

#### [Backup](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx#Security)

> BACKUP DATABASE and BACKUP LOG permissions default to members of the
>   sysadmin fixed server role and the db_owner and db_backupoperator
>   fixed database roles.